# The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable(Error occured on making ftp directory)

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, directory

I am developing a wpf application and I want to make a directory on ftp using C# with  different usernames and if it already exists then save files on existing directory.

I've successfully created the logic of checking the existing directory but while creating a new directory I've got an exception on runtime:

`The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).`

I've checked different solutions on the internet and most are saying that it is due to write permissions. I am assigning the ftp folder write permissions, but I am still having the problem. Please Help?

Here is my code:

```
    static void CreateFtpFolder(string source)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(source);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = false;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Proxy = null;

        FtpWebResponse ftpResp = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;

    }
```

I am having the error on `FtpWebResponse`.

Comment: Try using a command-line FTP client to replicate the error.  Perhaps the actual error being returned by the server is going to be more informative than what you're seeing in your code?  But yes, this does sound like a possible server-side permission issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code look fine.......you are saying that you have assigned permission too.
The only problem is that you may be passing a wrong "Source"which is causing problem..Check your source string it may have an error......

path should be like

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://host.com/directory123");
```

it mean directory will be created with name "directory12"
if your are specifying path like this

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://host.com/directory123/directory1234");
```

this mean "ftp://host.com/directory123/" should already exist and new directory will be created with name "directory1234"
hope it will help

Comment: Hi. I am getting the same error. The application works well for everyone else except this one client. We have been trying to check the Firewall but that hasn't given up anything to work with. It has been almost a month, trying to resolve this issue on a daily basis. Currently I remote to the machine, copy the file to my local PC, then use the same application with the same credentials and it works. Any ideas on why it fails for him?

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is a Windows Server-side permission issue and you have access to this FTP server, you may be able to resolve it by modifying the permission and adding 'Write' permission for the username that you are authenticating with on the actual physical directory.

e.g. If 'ftp://host/' points to 'c:\inetpub\ftproot' on your server, then allow 'Write' permission for the user on that directory.

I was setting up my own IIS 7 FTP server and spent a good hour or two trying to get such a simple snippet of C# client code to work, so thought I'd contribute for those in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error if the directory already exists. Pretty non-descriptive error message (lol). Must put a try catch around the call to request.GetResponse()

```
try
{
FtpWebResponse ftpResp = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;

}
catch ( Exception ex ) { /* ignore */ }
```

Comment: Not really a good idea. there are a lot of possible exceptions that could happen there, and you are ignoring them all.