# Error 550 File unavailable when downloading from FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, download

I had a little problem while downloading a file from FTP. I'm getting a error that says "the remote server returned an error (550) File unavailable (e.g, file not found, no access)."

The code is below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btntamam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     FtpWebRequest FTP;

try
{

FileStream SR = new FileStream("C:\\asd" + "\\list.gz", FileMode.Create);

FTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://xx.x.xx.xxx/" + "list.gz"));

FTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");

FTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FTP.UseBinary = true;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)FTP.GetResponse();

Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

long cl = response.ContentLength;

int bufferSize = 2048;
int readCount;

byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (readCount > 0)
{
    SR.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
ftpStream.Close();
SR.Close();
response.Close();
MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded!");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
    }
}
}
```

The code seems to be working, but it's unable to download the file I want. I've searched a lot but could not find any solutions..

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so post please

Comment: No theres no exception or error only when i run this code i get the i get the error(550) which i told before.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17166756/1134076

Comment: Just tested your code with my own FTP server. It works. So I guess the file you want to download is not stored at the server or maybe have another name?

Comment: Onam: I tried it it did not help thanks anyway.

Comment: MAV: But i tried it on command line and it works but could not work it with c#

Comment: @Mustafa Are you 1000% sure that the URI path is correct? As said, I got it working just by changing the path and the credentials.

Comment: Yea i tried it with another FTP server too and it worked you are right the person who wants me to do this program wants to go to another directory i think this code goes to home/root directory by default