# Assembly reference for filedownloader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

What is the assembly reference for a Filedownloader in c#?

I am looking for to download the files from ftp to my local drive 'c' ,

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

FileDownloader f = new FileDownloader();
```

which reference should I need to add for the  filedownloader?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694513/download-from-ftp-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to download files from FTP,and you don't have to use the `FileDownloader` class.
You can use this link for example: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711(v=vs.110).aspx".

You can also use an open source to do that, try looking at this link: "http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class"

There is an example of how simple it is to use (From the link above):

```
ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://10.10.10.10/", "user", "password");
ftpClient.download("etc/test.txt", @"C:\Users\metastruct\Desktop\test.txt");
```